# In C, how can you statically prepend the length of a fixed string to the start of that same string (BCPL-style)?

Tags: c, string, static

For static field names, I'd like some C compiler magic to statically prepend the length of the field name, so that rather than storing "LABEL" at compile time, it would instead store "\x05LABEL". (*People as ancient as me may recall that this was how BCPL stored its strings.*)

The best I can come up with to achieve this is a stupendously ugly (and long-winded) macro:

```
#define BCPL_STRING(STRING) \
   (sizeof(STRING) == 1) ? "\x00" STRING : \
   (sizeof(STRING) == 2) ? "\x01" STRING : \
   (sizeof(STRING) == 3) ? "\x02" STRING : \
   (sizeof(STRING) == 4) ? "\x03" STRING : \
   (sizeof(STRING) == 5) ? "\x04" STRING : \
[etc]
```

Is there a better way to achieve this in C at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

IMO you cant. You will get the string literal (the most likely compiler will optimize the code to the single string literal)

Any other form will require creating a normal variable and copying the data which can be only done at runtime.

BTW this macro will only work with ***string literals***. You cant pass the char array to it (it will not work). So its usage is limited to string literals.